# Changing a value in an array

Tags: ios, swift, collectionview

Upon selecting the custom cell, the item is `Bool` value should change from true to false or vice-versa. You can know when a cell has been selected by using the `didSelectItemAt` method in the `UICollectionViewDelegate` protocol.

This is what the instructor is asking us to do.

```
override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

        var item = shoppingListController.shoppingItems[indexPath.item]

        item.itemHasBeenAdded = true
}
```

this is what I have so far.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Be careful with this pattern:

```
var item = shoppingListController.shoppingItems[indexPath.item]
item.itemHasBeenAdded = true
```

That will work if your item in your array is a reference type (i.e., a `class`), as `item` will reference the instance that is in the array. But if it is a value type (i.e. a `struct`), this local `item` variable will end up being a copy of the object and you’ll end up changing `itemHasBeenAdded` in this copy, not updating the item in your array.

If it is a `struct`, you theoretically could copy the item back, e.g.

```
var item = shoppingListController.shoppingItems[indexPath.item]
item.itemHasBeenAdded.toggle()
shoppingListController.shoppingItems[indexPath.item] = item
```

Note, you said you wanted to “change from true to false or vice-versa”. In this case, I’m using `toggle` to switch back and forth from `true` to `false` and back.

Or, easier, just update the item in the array directly, which will work regardless of whether it is a reference type or value type, e.g.

```
shoppingListController.shoppingItems[indexPath.item].itemHasBeenAdded.toggle()
```

Needless to say, this caveat regarding the local `item` variable is only applicable if the items in your array are, themselves, value types (a `struct`). If it’s a `class`, you’ll be fine either way. But you’ll still want to use `toggle` to have this one method switch the `Bool` back and forth.

Answer (score 1):

You can write your code to change the value of the Boolean to the opposite value upon selection like this :

```
override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

        var item = shoppingListController.shoppingItems[indexPath.item]

        item.itemHasBeenAdded = !item.itemHasBeenAdded
}
```

Edit: as art-of-dreams said, this code will produce the same effect:

```
item.itemHasBeenAdded.toggle()
```

Comment: Bool type has method `toggle` for this, so it's possible to just write `item.itemHasBeenAdded.toggle()`